# Flatting list in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I flat list in dictionary if I have something like this:

```
Object {'a': '48',
       'b': '24',
       'c':[{'cA':'20', 'cB':'42', 'cC':'55'}, {'c1':'21', 'c2':'43','c3':'58'}],
       'd':'44',
       'e':'32',}
```

That's parsed XML file, in XML C has a structure like this:

```
<p name = "a">48<\p>
<p name = "b">24<\p>
<list name ="C">
    <item>
            <cA>20<\cA>
            <cB>42<\cB>
            <cC>55<\cC>
    <\item>
    <item>
            <c1>21<\c1>
            <c2>43<\c2>
            <c3>58<\c3>
    <\item>
<\list>
<p name = "D">44<\p>
<p name = "e">32<\p>
```

Desired output would be :

```
Object {'a':'48', 
        'b':'24',
        'cA':'20', 
        'cB':'42', 
        'cC':'55',
        'c1':'21', 
        'c2':'43', 
        'c3':'58'
        'd':'44',
        'e':'32'}
```

Comment: Is it ever going to be deeper than that? Or is it only ever going to be as deep as a dictionary with a list of dictionaries?

Comment: I hope you are aware that dictionaries are not ordered (generally)

Comment: @Hoopdady I have edited my quastion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

supposing that you have fixed depth and contain "flat" dictionaries (that's a lot of "supposing", I know), you can iterate through the input dict and check for type of the values.

If value is a `list`, update the output dict with the items of the list, else update with the original items

```
d= {'a1': '48',
'b': '24',
'c':[{'cA':'20', 'cB':'42', 'cC':'55'}, {'c1':'21', 'c2':'43', 'c3':'58'}],
'd':'44',
'e':'32'}

new_d = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v,list):
        for v1 in v:
            new_d.update(v1)
    else:
        new_d[k] = v
```

result:

```
{'c2': '43', 'a1': '48', 'c3': '58', 'b': '24', 'cC': '55', 'd': '44', 'cA': '20', 'cB': '42', 'e': '32', 'c1': '21'}
```